# Does changing wordpress settings general language affect seo?

Tags: seo, wordpress, language

When I did an SEO check on my website, it was recommended that...

> The given language en does not conform with the detected language de.

I know I can change the language under `Settings>General>Language`, but my first question is:

1. Does this really matter?
2. Is there a way to set the language for SEO but leave the backstage in english?

I have only found instructions on how to change the entire website. One the SEO matter, good information is hard to come by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relation between the Wordpress administration language and the site language. 
You can set language options that affect SEO through these two ways:

- [International targeting](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/i18n?hl=en) (Google Search Console)
- [Hreflang tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en)

Nothing else would impact the SEO strategy. Many people still believe that `HTML lang` is used by searchers but, [at least Google, ignore it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=3354&v=isW-Ke-AJJU):

> We don't use that at all. So we use the hreflang links if you have that if you have different language versions. But the language attribute within the HTML markup is something we don't use at all. We've found that this language markup is something that is almost always wrong. So we tend to ignore that.